# Turn off quoted-printable encoding in sendmail

Tags: email, sendmail

i send a mail from a monitoring system to another linux box that handles and parses the mail. The mail is sent with the following headers:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

the problem is that the last line of the mail gets split and a = sign gets added:

CRIT - 93.2% used (466.06 of 500.0 GB), (levels at 80.00/90.00%), trend=

: +5.66MB / 24 hours=

do you have any idea how can i prevent that quote-printable problem so that the last line on the mail is not altered by the receiving MUA.

thank you

Mario.

Comment: Which software do you use to send email? Sendmail is not the most likely suspect for breaking such _short_ lines (72 chars).

Comment: Hello,
the mail is sent from nagios(check_mk), so the mail is sent by apache i think.

Comment: Very quick search suggests that `nagios` uses `mailx` to send email [see `commands.cfg` configuration file ]. Which of the two versions of `mailx` do you use? [bsd or heirloom]

Answer (score 0):

quoted-printable does this by design,  special characters are replaced
such that \r\l or \n are encoded.

The email client sees the mime-header
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
and reverses that to get back the original formatting.